# Dealing with SQL Server Deadlock with Python

Tags: python, sql-server, python-2.7, try-catch, database-deadlocks

What is the best way to deal with the

> 1205 "deadlock victim"

error when calling SQL Server from Python?

The issue arises when I have multiple Python scripts running, and all are attempting to update a table with a `MERGE` statement which adds a row if it doesn't yet exist (this query will be called millions of times in each script).

```
MERGE table_name as table  // including UPDLOCK or ROWLOCK eventually 
                           //      results in deadlock
USING ( VALUES ( ... ) )
    AS row( ... )
    ON table.feature = row.feature
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (...)
    VALUES (...)
```

The scripts require immediate access to the table to access the unique id assigned to the row.

Eventually, one of the scripts raises an `OperationalError`:

> Transaction (Process ID 52) was deadlocked on lock  resources with
>   another process and has been chosen as  the deadlock victim. Rerun the
>   transaction.

#### 1) I have tried using a try-except block around the call in Python:

```
while True:
    try:
        cur.execute(stmt)
        break
    except OperationalError:
        continue
```

This approach slows the process down considerably. Also, I think I might be doing this incorrectly (I think I might need to reset the connection...).

#### 2) Use a try-catch in SQL Server (something like below...):

```
WHILE 1 = 1
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        MERGE statement      // see above
        BREAK
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber
        ROLLBACK
        CONTINUE
    END CATCH;
END
```

#### 3) Something else?

Thanks for your help. And let me know if you need additional details, etc.

I am using Python 2.7, SQL Server 2008, and pymssql to make the connection.

Comment: have you tried to put them in [transaction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190295.aspx)

Comment: No, I haven't. Forgive my ignorance, but how would that help?

Comment: check that link on `transaction` word, a little bit of reading :) I think that should fix deadlock victims, and not executing queries.

Comment: @mirkobrankovic: Placing each MERGE into a `TRANSACTION` didn't help. Did you mean placing all the MERGE statements into a single `TRANSACTION`? That won't work since all the scripts require immediate access to these updates, and I don't have enough memory to store all the information.

Comment: yes it's tricky. inserts aren't problem, deadlock I have encountered only on simultanius update/delete (locking the whole table), so if adding every merdge into a transaction doesn't help, than i'm sorry i have no more ideas. :|